# Using the Trapezoidal rule

Tags: approximation

QUESTION:  [image]

I am doing this question using a tabular method of solving trapezoidal approx.
and I came up with an answer as 1.1128153  but this answer is not on the above question answer list then I just assumed 1.56396455.
please someone help me here, check my working on image file attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The last line: the weight should be 1, not 2.

Comment: i notice that and by making it to  1; i get the result to be 1.065406203 which is  still not in the list.

Comment: The answer is the middle one. The $y_i$ column contain the values of a function, not the ratios of $x_i$'s. See my spreadsheet. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxfu6db9v5yd144/trapezoid.xls?dl=0 It will be removed in few hours :)